# How to display value entered in apex:inputText as numbers with commas - currency format

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am using apex:inputText that holds a string with number(Integer) at controller side. Is there any way to display it as Number with commas (in USD Currency format)after typing input.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Salesforce Developer,

If it has to be an `apex:inputText` using jQuery and jMaskedInput should solve your problem. All Input in the `apex:inputText` should then be masked as the format you choose.

```
<apex:page >    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQuery}"/>   
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JMaskedInput}"/> 
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".curr-mask").mask("999 999 999.99"); 
        }); 
    </script>   
    <apex:form id="testform" > 
        <apex:inputText id="txtCurr" styleClass="curr-mask"/> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image: InputText]

Some older Post in the developerforce forums: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095o2IAA

Comment: I tried to get those libraries on google. But no luck. can you help me out for giving those resource library links

Comment: jQuery you can get from the jQuery main page: https://jquery.com/download/
jMaskedInput can be aquired from their github: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput
you need to upload the two .js files to your salesforce instance as static ressource. After that you can use them as described above with $Ressource. prefix.